# Drupal 7 add block of text to front page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, content-type

I'm new to Drupal but I've found my way around it pretty easily.  There's just one thing I haven't found out how to do, and it's so simple it has to be possible.

I created a template for the site's homepage as it will have a different layout (did it creating page--front.tpl-php).  This page will display only the main menu, an image and a text of the company's mission statement.  I've done everything but the mission text and I have no idea how to do just that: simply put a block of text there.

I know I can hard-code it on the HTML but I want my client to be able to change it eventually if he wants to, in a graphic way.  I tried creating a content type but I can't remove the title field and some submitted info; I thought of using Views but it seems too complicated for what I need, isn't it?

The image I used is hard-coded on he HTML as I know it won't change, but maybe I should have created a view with both the image and the text?  But then how would I get rid of the title field and submission info?

Can someone please suggest the best way, if possible, to do this?  Perhaps I'm over-complicating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a region in your theme and then put a block into that region only on the home page.

In mytheme.info:

```
...
regions[front] = Front Page Text
...
```

In page--front.tpl.php:

```
echo render($page['front']);
```

Then in your blocks administration page create a block and assign it to the "Front Page Text" region with the content you want to output. You could also limit the block's visibility to `<front>` if you want to be sure, although if you don't output that region in any other template file it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Worked great, you helped me a lot :)